# Can I replicate data from Multiple S3 buckets to a single S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I ave a requirement where I want to copy/merge data from multiple S3 buckets to a single S3 bucket natively. I can do this using Glue or other AWS services. However, I want to see if this can be done natively using S3 cross region replication

```
Bucket 1 ---> Bucket A
Bucket 2 ---> Bucket A
Bucket 3 ---> Bucket A
```

The buckets could be in the same or different regions.

Thanks

Comment: Give it a try and let us know what you find!

Comment: Try what? Did you post a solution?

Comment: You say "I want to see if this can be done", so please attempt it yourself. If you run into a _specific_ issue, please post the details and people would be happy to assist. We'd be interested to know what you find!

Comment: I can try CRR. I want to know if there are any alternate means

Comment: S3 Cross-Region Replication would be the optimal way to do this. You might need to have different destination prefixes so the replications do not conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was trying to achieve the same outcome via S3 Replication, in my particular example I was trying to overwrite the same object in the hub bucket from multiple spoke buckets, unfortunately that setup is not support (confirmed with AWS SA)

This is the setup diagram

```
Bucket B -> Bucket A (edl.txt)
Bucket C -> Bucket A (edl.txt)
```

Once the object `edl.txt` is replicated into `Bucket A` from `Bucket B`, it's state is `REPLICA` is it can't be further updated via replication from the `Bucket C`

The workaround solution would be to create a lambda function triggered via S3 event in the account where `Bucket A` is located that would re-upload `eld.txt` object back to `Bucket A` so it's not consider as a `REPLICA` anymore but appears as a locally uploaded file. In this case it can be further updated via replication